# VueJS parameters do not work correctly in the page

Tags: javascript, typescript, vue.js

I wrote my `vue` in an external file and added it to the bottom of the page but it does not work completely. For example, when using `v-model`, the page contains an error:

> Error compiling template

When the page loads, I give my data from the API and put it in a parameter but my template shows the parameter as empty.  In my dev tools, it shows me that the API responded with all my data.

Here is my `get_Data` method :

```
get_type_data() {
    get_data().subscribe(function (x: any) {
        this.types = x.data;
        console.log(this.types);
    });
},
```

In the console it shows the right values but when I use it in the template it is empty.  What should i do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a fat arrow notation ..

```
get_type_data() {
            get_data().subscribe(x => {
                this.types = x.data;
                console.log(this.types);
            });
        },
```